# Inconsistent printing with CUPS on Raspberry Pi

Tags: bash, printing, raspberry-pi, thermal-printer, cups

I am printing an image with a thermal printer off of a raspberry pi. This works fine most of the time but I have an issue where the job never completes.

The command is just a simple: `lp <filename>` and I have the thermal printer as my default. This works but occasionally, it won't print in that terminal. Then just opening a new terminal and sending the same exact command works. I've had to just have a handful of terminals open and jump between them until one of them prints it.

Does anyone have any insight to why this would be happening and what a possible solution might be?

I am running this from:
Raspbian Stretch
CUPS v2.2.1
Zebra ZD410

Here is the end of the output of an unsuccessful job (Job 118) and successful job (Job 119) from /var/logs/cups/error_log

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a very similar issue to the one you are describing with Zebra ZD410 printers and cups printing from RaspberryPi.

By default, between each print job cups will reattach the usb printer. The ZD410 printer does not like when cups does that and the next print job will appear to go to the printer, but it won't print and there will be nothing in the logs that show any errors. This happens intermittently but frequently enough to make the printer unusable.

I was able to fix this problem by deleting the ZD410 printer from cups and adding it back using lpadmin and putting this configuration flag at the end of the lpadmin -p command:

`-o usb-no-reattach-default=true`

Try my suggestion and please let me know if it resolves your issue. Hopefully, this will help others with this problem as well.

Comment: huh. That's interesting. Thank you for the insight on what's happening behind the scenes. That makes a lot of sense for the issue I was seeing.

Comment: It's been so long since I've worked on that but I believe my solution was to scrap the RPI altogether. I used a windows pc stick and wrote a Node.JS server to run locally and manage the printing logic. I was working on this project at a previous company so I won't be able to test your suggestion but I believe that would work based on my experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not even name the exact Linux distro you are running, and which version of CUPS this involves.

No idea what your problem is...

But here is an idea how to start narrowing it down:

1. Enable *`LogLevel debug`* in *`/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`* and re-start the CUPS daemon.
2. Now you can follow whatever CUPS does with your print jobs:

   ```
    less /var/log/cups/error_log
   ```

This may give you a hint. Note, that all lines in the log starting with *`E`* denote an message with log level 'error'. (*`I`* denotes log level 'info', *`W`* is 'warning' and *`N`* is 'notice'.)

---

There's one more thing you could do:

- *Determine, if it happens that exactly the same job file prints sometimes or doesn't print at other times.* If so, it seems a "random" failure of the print device, or the transfer path from CUPS to the printer where some bit flip introduces an error. If not (the same file never prints), then this gives you another hint to narrow down the real problem.

Comment: I've updated with system information. Looking into the debug log shows what appears to be the same thing when it succeeds or fails. There are no errors and it appears to have been sent to the printer. The printer has a data feed indicator light. On a successful print, the light blinks a few times during the print. On a failed print, the light blinks once. As far as I can tell, this is the only thing different between a successful print or unsuccessful print. The log file is rather large but I can put the sections from each print on some cloud and link it if that would be helpful.

Comment: If you see *"what appears to be the same thing when it succeeds or fails"*, then it appears to not be CUPS' fault. The printer receives the same data, but intermittently treats it differently. To confirm, search (for a failed job) all lines with *"Job XYZ"* where XYZ is the CUPS job ID and see if it ends in lines *"PID NNNNN (/usr/lib/cups/backend/ABC) exited with no errors"* ... *"Job completed."* ... *"Removing document files."* If you see these lines, CUPS spooled the print data off to the print device without failure.

Comment: @AlexDeCamillo: A command to do that is *`grep "Job XYZ" /var/log/cups/error_log | less`*.

Comment: I've updated my post with an image of the bottom of the output for both of those. It appears that the issue must be with the printer